# Cannot remove the first level element in JSON dictionary python

Tags: python, json

This is my JSON array:

```
amenities =  {
      "9": {
        "id": "9",
        "name": "Fitness facilities"
      },
      "2820": {
        "id": "2820",
        "name": "Number of indoor pools - 10",
        "value": 10
      }
    },
```

Now I want to make it like this by removing the first level element because it is similar to 'id':

```
amenities =  {
     ({"id": "9","name": "Fitness facilities"}),
       ({"id": "2820","name": "Number of indoor pools - 10","value": 10})
    }
```

This is the dataframe I have, 'amenities' column's type is string:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/th47v.png%5D)

This is the code I wrote to do it:

```
amenities_df['amenities_list'] = amenities_df['amenities'].map(lambda amenities_dict: amenities_dict.values() if isinstance(amenities, dict) else amenities_dict)
```

But I cannot remove the first level element.

What did I go wrong? Please help.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want a list, not a dictionary:

```
amenities = [*amenities.values()]
```

Result:

```
[{'id': '9', 'name': 'Fitness facilities'}, {'id': '2820', 'name': 'Number of indoor pools - 10', 'value': 10}]
```

Comment: Thank you. I have an error when trying that: "TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable"

Comment: @QuynhAnhNguyen are you sure that amenities is a list? Are you sure it's not something else?

Comment: I checked the type, it's a str. So does it mean I have to convert the string to a list?

Comment: @QuynhAnhNguyen You should update your question with precise details. How can we know it's a string if you put a list in the question? :) Please review your question

Comment: I added the details to the question. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: I solved the problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the best option here is not to "remove" the first level so much as rename it.

What you are working with is a python dictionary and it requires key - value pairs. The dictionary that you said you desire is not a correct dictionary. It does not have keys and values.

```
amenities =  {
     ({"id": "9","name": "Fitness facilities"}),
       ({"id": "2820","name": "Number of indoor pools - 10","value": 10})
    }
```

I see a couple of options here. One, you could have a list of dictionaries:

```
dict_list = [
    {"id": "9","name": "Fitness facilities"},
    {"id": "2820","name": "Number of indoor pools - 10","value": 10}
]
```

which will "remove" the top level but is no longer a dictionary data structure. It's a list containing dictionaries.

Second, you could rename the top level so that it is not the same as the `id` element.

```
updated_dict = {}
for i, k in enumerate(amenities.keys()):
    updated_dict[i] = amenities[k]
```

which results in

```
{0: {'id': '9', 'name': 'Fitness facilities'},
 1: {'id': '2820', 'name': 'Number of indoor pools - 10', 'value': 10}}
```

Comment: My original JSON array is something like this: "{'2137': {'id': '2137', 'name': '全館禁煙'}, '369': {'id': '369', 'name': 'ランドリー設備'}". What I want to do is remove number "2137" and "269", so that it will become  {{'id': '2137', 'name': '全館禁煙'}, {'id': '369', 'name': 'ランドリー設備'}}

Comment: @QuynhAnhNguyen First of all, there's no such thing as a JSON array. You may have an array, or a list, or a dictionary. It actually looks like you are working with a string representation of a dictionary if the quotation marks you put are correct. So first you must convert the string to a dictionary. Then, as I said in my answer, there is no such thing as a dictionary that does not have key/value pairs. what you are asking for `{{key1 : value1}, {key2 : value2}}` is a dictionary without keys. So, you must convert it to a list if you don't want the top level. Otherwise, you need top-level keys.

Comment: Thank you very much. I solved the problem.